# asp.net panel defaultbutton doesn't work

Tags: asp.net

I got some panels with textfields & buttons. My problem is, that even though that I have a panel with a defaultbutton, it still uses the first button on the page when ever i'm clicking enter. I've done this a lot of times, but suddenly it stopped working?

```
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlWrite"  DefaultButton="btnWallSubmit" runat="server">
       <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><asp:Literal ID="litName" runat="server" /></span>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtMind" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" aria-label="..." placeholder="What's on your mind?" />
       <div class="input-group-btn">
          <asp:Button ID="btnWallSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Publish!" OnClick="btnWallSubmit_Click" />
       </div>
</div>
<br />
</asp:Panel>
```

But it still use the login button(Which is on the masterpage) when I'm clicking enter.

//EDIT

Iv'e tried with these browsers: Google Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Edge & Internet Explorer. It seems that it only works on Edge & Explorer.

Comment: Is it not working even if the focus is on the Panel, not any other element outside the panel?

Comment: Nope, not working even if the focus is inside the panel

Answer (score 0):

Is your login button on your masterpage inside a panel with DefaultButton set?
If so, you can override the masterpage default button on your content page by adding the following inside the `Page_Load` of your content page like this...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form.DefaultButton = this.btnWallSubmit.UniqueID;
}
```

Comment: Hi. It doesn't seems to do the trick. It still uses the masterpage login

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by moving my login modal box / panel at the almost bottom of the masterpage.